# Adding sections and header UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView using an accordion view. and id like to separate the parent cells into 2 sections with headers but not too sure how to go bout doing so as i have never used an accordion view before and the IB is eliminated as it is mainly code based. Code below:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return[topItems count] + ((currentExpandedIndex > -1) ? [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count] : 0);
}

- (ACNBookingCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    // Define cell identifiers
    static NSString *ParentCellIdentifier       = @"ParentCell";
    static NSString *ChildCellIdentifier        = @"ChildCell";

    // Check to see if cell isChild
    BOOL isChild = currentExpandedIndex > -1 && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex && indexPath.row <= currentExpandedIndex + [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count];

    // Initialise cell
    ACNBookingCell *cell;

    if (isChild && currentExpandedIndex == 0) {

    }
    else if (isChild) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChildCellIdentifier];
    }
    else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier];
    }
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ACNBookingCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier];
    }

    // Current Orders cell
    if (isChild && currentExpandedIndex == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Child Cell";
    }
    // History cell
    else if (isChild && currentExpandedIndex == 2) {

    }
    // Favorites cell
    else if (isChild) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Child Cell";
    }
    // Parent cell
    else {
        int topIndex = (currentExpandedIndex > -1 && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex) ? (int)indexPath.row - (int)[[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count] : (int)indexPath.row;
        cell.cellTitle.text = [topItems objectAtIndex:topIndex];

        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);


        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cell.icon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"calendar"];
                break;
            case 1:
                cell.icon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"globe"];
                break;
            case 2:
                cell.icon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"taxi"];
                break;
            case 3:
                cell.icon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hotel"];
                break;
            case 4:
                cell.icon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"calendar"];
                break;
            case 5:
                cell.icon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"taxi"];
                break;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    ACNBookingCell *cell = (ACNBookingCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Check to see if cell isChild
    BOOL isChild = currentExpandedIndex > -1 && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex && indexPath.row <= currentExpandedIndex + [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count];

    // Action behind Child cell
    if (isChild) {

        if (currentExpandedIndex == 0) {
            childIndexPath = indexPath;
        }
        else if (currentExpandedIndex == 2) {
            childIndexPath = indexPath;
        }
        return;
    }

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    // Expand parent cell to show child cells
    if (currentExpandedIndex == indexPath.row) {

        cell.arrowImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"collapse"];

        [self collapseSubItemsAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
        currentExpandedIndex = -1;
    }
    // Collapse parent cell and hide child cells
    else {

        cell.arrowImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"drop_down"];

        BOOL shouldCollapse = currentExpandedIndex > -1;

        if (shouldCollapse) {
            [self collapseSubItemsAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
        }

        currentExpandedIndex = (shouldCollapse && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex) ? (int)indexPath.row - (int)[[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count] : (int)indexPath.row;

        [self expandItemAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: You have posted a bunch of code but you have not provided any details about what the issue is. What exactly is wrong with the code you posted? What issue are you having? What does it do compared to what you want it to do? Update your question with more relevant details.

Comment: Essentially the code i have is fine. but id like to implement into this code 2 sections with headers. And upon looking around ive seen its done in this section of code. @rmaddy

Comment: So attempt to update your code to provide two sections. If you run into a problem doing so, update your question with that code and explain what issue you are having. So far it seems you've made no attempt to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the numberOfSections to 2 or anything u want. Then you can change the headers und die cell's in the section.